# Why not to use git for large files?

Tags: git, large-files, git-lfs

I just had a project in which I had to store a csv file together with git (by using LFS). So I wonder why Git LFS should be used in these cases. Doesn't git only track the changes between Versions?

Comment: No, Git stores snapshots. Each version of the file is stored entirely.

Comment: CSV files, even if large, are not the "sweet spot" of what LFS was designed to deal with.  In fact you may run into some of LFS's "rough edges" when using it with a file of this type (such as lack of an LFS-aware merge tool, lack of autocrlf support...).  LFS is at its best with large **binary** files; with these files (1) git wasn't going to do good merge work anyway; (2) autocrlf or other textual filtering are not an issue; (3) binary files may not behave as well on average with respect to deltafication (when packed)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would you advice to do for the csv file then?