# Best way to store large csv files with a git project

Tags: git, git-lfs

Hey I have another question regarding this one: [Why not to use git for large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680993/why-not-to-use-git-for-large-files?noredirect=1#comment78321214_45680993).
One user in the comment section mentions that git LFS is not really made to store large csv files. So now my question is, what would be a better way? Should I maybe just use git? But what about the problems with large files in history then?

Comment: S3 or another cloud storage provider is an option. You can save "master" as `some-file-name.csv` and when updating it, change the name of the previous master to `some-file-name_timestamp.csv` and save the newest version as your "master" file. Depending on how large the file is and how often it changes this may not be feasible though.

Comment: The file is "only" about one gigabyte in size and does not change to often. So do you mean I can set it up in a way that the S3 storage is connected to git?

Answer (score 0):

For large CVS file, you can replicate what Git LFS does, and add your own [smudge/clean content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041055/63094)

The `smudge` script would, on checkout, fetch your CVS file from an external storage (for instance S3, as mentioned in the comments).

The `clean` script would, on commit, check if the file has changed, and upload it back, which should not happen often according to you.

That way, you avoid keeping a large text file in your Git repo.